# How to add a text to a levelplot?

Tags: r, raster

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
 r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
 r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
levelplot(r)
```

I want to put a word (a text) that is "Original map" under the xlab "Longitude"

Is this possible?

Comment: `levelplot(r, xlab = 'Longitude\nOriginal map')` works although it changes the scaling a bit. not sure of the proper way to do this for this package

Comment: I do not want to use xlab because it changes the scale so i want to put the text on the plot without changing anything

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean with "changes the scale". I have used the solution of @rawr and it works correctly for me. On the other hand, you could try `levelplot(r, margin = FALSE, sub = 'Original Map')` if you don't need the marginal plots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a manual solution, but you can use `mtext` to place text around margins with `line` and `adj` parameters to put it where you want (or `text`).

```
plot.new()  # open new plot
 r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
 r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
levelplot(r)

mtext("Original map", 1, line=-3.4, adj=0.4)
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the location of the text changes if you resize the graphical window.

Comment: @OscarPerpiñán that is what I meant by a "manual" solution, meaning it is not going to automatically work sadly.

Answer (score 0):

With the grid library you can place text, as well.

```
plot.new()  # open new plot
 r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
 r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
levelplot(r)
library(grid)
trellis.focus("panel", 1, 1, clip.off = TRUE,highlight=TRUE)
grid.text("Hello World!", x = 0.5, y = 0.5,gp = gpar(fontsize = 6))
trellis.unfocus()
```